# Connecting PCI Root Port and M.2 Drives via single port

Tags: linux, motherboard, pci-express

I have a system with a single PCIe x8 slot and a single M.2 slot. I have a device that will act as a root port that needs to connect as well as a M.2 drive. Looking at lspci and dmidecode I see that my PCIe slot and my M.2 slot are on different PCI busses.

How can I connect these 2 devices such that the root port devices can control the M.2 drive and not the linux kernel?

My initial plan was simply to use pci commands to remove the M.2 drive from the kernel but if they are on different busses I think that means they are not connected before the Root Complex meaning they can't talk without the CPU in the middle.

Looking online I find that PCI-to-PCI bridges were created to increase fanout of a single port on a motherboard so I was thinking get a bridge and connect it to my single card slot and then connect both behind that. Thing is, I can't find such a card. I can find passive backplanes but my Root Port device is powered via PCI so the passive cards will not work I need a powered backplane that connects multiple devices behind either a bridge or a switch.

Does anyone know of such a part or an alternative solution?

Comment: Could you be more specific about *what exactly* is the device "that will act as a root port, and which needs to connect to the M.2 device"? My suspicion is that this device, whatever it is, has physical connections for M.2, and the M.2 device will need to be plugged into those. So having an M.2 device plugged in somewhere else won't help, even if that device is reachable in principle through the PCIe hierarchy. But maybe I misunderstood your description of the situation. In any case, please give actual names.

Comment: The device in question is a FPGA I'm programming via Xilinx tools. The current version has a single PCIe x8 interface that I am connecting to the motherboard. I can talk to Linux via this interface but we need to test for standalone capability. I would use a passive backplane but the FPGA is powered via the PCIe rail so I would need some kind of externally powered passive PCIe backplane which I can't find. In V2 of the board there will be a 2nd PCIe interface I can connect to to solve the problem but sadly that's not the case in the immediate.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand it. *Which* FPGA exactly are you using? I can't google for documentation if you are so vague. PCIe has a *single* root complex, and if you connect the FPGA to the motherboard, that means the root complex is on the motherboard, and the FPGA is downstream of this root complex. In particular, the FPGA cannot act itself as root complex. The FPGA can use peer-to-peer transfers to access other PCIe parts (e.g. M.2, if it's using PCIe and not something else), but you can't test it behaving as a root in this way.

Comment: So no kind of backplane is going to solve this problem. Yes, a second PCIe interface on the FPGA acting as root complex would solve it. How is the FPGA supposed to be powered in stand-alone mode in the first place, if the PCIe connection acts as root complex and will have other devices which also need to be powered?

Comment: Sorry for delay missed message. The specific FPGA is a Kintex Ultrascale xcku095-ffva1156-2-e. This is an inhouse board using that chip so not much of a datasheet for you to find. I understood PCIe has 1 root complex but some documents I read gave me the impression you can have multiple root ports within 1 root complex to create sub hierarchies. Is that not the case? As for how this was supposed to be standalone. This is primarily a short term problem. The original board was not meant for standalone and I've been asked to shoe horn the capability short term for testing.

Comment: Also do I have a missunderstanding on what a backplane does? While some appeared to be PCI-to-PCI bridges I believed others were strictly passive implying they were nothing more then traces connecting sockets. If that second option was externally powered with no interface to a motherboard would that not enable me to operate in standalone? I understand most motherboards have PCI switches connected to the northbridge but for a bare bones test I don't think they would be necessary correct?

Comment: Yes, you can have a root complex with multiple ports, but then that root complex is a unit, and knows how to make those ports work together. Two root complexes that are completely independent are very different from one root complex with multiple ports. And yes, if I understood your description correctly, a "backplane" or whatever you'd like to name it that just connects traces and feeds in external power would allow stand-alone testing while not connected to the motherboard (so no direct debugging). No, I have no idea where to get such a "backplane".

Comment: So just to clarify. From what I can tell with Vivado most IP creates a root port not a root complex which are both different from endpoints. Correct? I can have multiple root ports in a single root complex but they needed to be designed that way which obviously my motherboard was not. So it simply will not allow the root port subgroup. Correct? Here is where I'm basing this idea from: https://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/236376/Spring2016/ho/WCFiles/chipset_microarch.pdf Sorry for the confusion on terms here I'm new to PCIe.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vivado, but if you can synthesize root ports, you'll probably also have some way to aggregate them into the root complex of the FPGA. But that's not the point at all, the point is (unless I am misunderstanding something in your description completely) that you have a motherboard which already has a root complex, and you want to connect it to the FPGA with a second (synthesized) root port or ports in a root complex using the PCIe connection. And that's the part that is not going to work.

Comment: gotcha thank you. I can't have multiple root ports on a root complex. That was a miss understanding on my part on how PCI works.